# SWITCH statement isn't working - Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm making a program to calculate the speed of sound through a certain material. Here is the code:

```
  switch (user_Choice)
 {
case 1:
  System.out.println("The sound wave took " + speed.getSpeedInAir() + " seconds to travel through " +
                     distance + " feet of Air.");
  break;

case 2:
  System.out.println("The sound wave took " + speed.getSpeedInWater() + " seconds to travel through " +
                     distance + " feet of Water.");
  break;

case 3:
  System.out.println("The sound wave took " + speed.getSpeedInSteel() + " seconds to travel through " +
                     distance + " feet of Steel.");
  break;

default:
  System.out.println("Not a valid input.");}
```

I don't know why this isn't working. Can I not have that many "+" signs per case?

EDIT: Here is the user_Choice input

```
System.out.println("Pick a medium (1, 2, or 3):\n1. Air\n2. Water\n3. Steel");
user_Choice = kbReader.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the distance the sound wave traveled in feet: ");
distance = kbReader.nextDouble();
SpeedOfSound speed = new SpeedOfSound(distance);
```

Comment: Specify what does `isn't working` means? How it should work?

Comment: It always shows the default option? How are you reading user_Choice var?

Comment: What is `user_Choice`? How does it get its value?

Comment: We need more information as to what it is doing.  Does it produce an error?  Does it compile?  If it doesn't what is the stack trace?  I don't see anything in this snippet that is syntactically incorrect, and you can have just about anything in a case statement (whole program executions even).

Comment: post the code showing `user_Choice` input

Comment: Default is selected if your case is not among 3 choices provided 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific... It only shows the default one.  It should use the methods in another class to get the speed in that material. user_Choice is used as an Int. I have a menu that basically says, "Pick a material (1-3)"...

Comment: If your `user_Choice` is a integer variable of value between 1 to 3 it will enter the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `kbReader` is a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) remember that `nextInt()` and `nextDouble()` need a `nextLine()` [in order to get rid of the `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/3735079). Calling `nextDouble()` after `nextInt()` will give to `distance` the value `null`.

A workaround is to add a `nextLine()` after the first `nextInt()`:

```
System.out.println("Pick a medium (1, 2, or 3):\n1. Air\n2. Water\n3. Steel");
user_Choice = kbReader.nextInt();
kbReader.nextLine(); //Consumes the \n (new line) character.
System.out.print("Enter the distance the sound wave traveled in feet: ");
distance = kbReader.nextDouble();
SpeedOfSound speed = new SpeedOfSound(distance);
```

If before your `user_Choice = kbReader.nextInt();` you are performing another `nextInt()` or similar, the `switch` will always choose the default value, since `user_Choice` is `null`.

Comment: @Dalton Craig please make sure that you are edits are valid and also you enter valid edit summary